# Vuetify Data-Table Pagination Data Elements

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component, vuetify.js

I have a `data-table` that has thousands of data inputs in it. Thus I am using the built in `Vuetify` pagination for loading only 5, 10, or 25 items on the table at once.

What I need to do though is know what data is on the table at one time. For instance if I am on page 2 of the table and it is displaying data: *d6, d7, d8, d9, and d10*, I want to be able to store those 5 items in a list different than my `mainData` list that way I can manipulate them all at once. I don't know how to do this as I don't know how to access the data on the page without a click action happening and I don't know how to know which page I am currently on or how many items are being displayed on the page.

If I could either on the page for the `data-table` loading, know which items are loaded or know which page I am on and how many items are currently being displayed (so I can calculate which items are on the page), that would be idea. But I don't know how to do either of those to things.

Is there anyway to figure this what items are being currently displayed?

Comment: Post the code..

Comment: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/vVJdbY?editors=1010#anon-login My code is work code, but here is a simulated version of it

Comment: i could give you a solution without using vuetify data table, i can give the current page content, index  ..., if you still are having the problem relpy to my comment

Comment: Any help at this point would be helpful. Though I can't change from using vuetify data table

Answer (score 0):

You have access already to the items show in the data table.
it is in you're this.desserts
If you need to create a duplicate for editing

```
this.newDesserts = {...this.desserts};
```

Comment: I know that but I need to know what is currently being display not what all my data is since I have over a thousand data points. For instance, when the table displays 5 items at a time, page one will display data d1, d2, d3, d4, d5 and page 2 will display d2, d3, d4, d5, d6. I need to find out a way to either know what page I am on and how many items are being displayed so I can calculate which items in this.dessert are being displayed or on load find out which items are being displayed and store them in a display[] array.